# Finding the transition matrix of a set

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I have a question here:

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to approach it.

I've written it out as the following matrix here:

$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&1&0 \\ 1&-2&1 \\ 1&-1&1 \end{bmatrix}$

But I'm not sure where I'm supposed to go from here in finding the transition matrix. I've seen examples of these types of questions, but they usually have another vector to find the matrix that will change bases.

Answer (score 1):

Let $e:=e_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}=\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and let $B=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3}\}=\{(1,1,0),(1,-2,1),(1,-1,1)\}$ as in your problem. So,you need to find
$$[A]_{B\to e}=\begin{pmatrix} \uparrow
 & \uparrow
 & \uparrow \\
[v_{1}]_{e} & [v_{2}]_{e} & [v_{3}]_{e} \\
\downarrow
 & \downarrow
 & \downarrow
  \end{pmatrix} $$
where $[v_{i}]_{e}$ for $i=1,2,3$ denote [coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) respecto to basis $e$.

Now, by definition we can see for example that $\left[v_{1} \right]_{e}=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}\iff \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}=a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \implies [v_{1}]_{e}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$
Similary with $[v_{2}]_{e}$ and $[v_{3}]_{e}$
Finally, we obtain $$\boxed{[A]_{B\to e}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -2 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Just curious, how would you find the transition matrix for the other way around, so from R3 to $B$?

Comment: If you know both bases, then  is analogous. The transition matrix from $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ to $B$ would look like $[B]_{e_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}\to B}=\begin{pmatrix} \uparrow & \uparrow & \uparrow \\ [e_{1}]_{B}  & [e_{2}]_{B} & [e_{3}]_{B} \\ \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Ramanjuan So, essentially: Let :=ℝ3={(1,1,0),(1,−2,1),(1,−1,1)} and let ={1,2,3}={(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)} and then proceed the same way?